# add a navigation drawer to swipe view

Tags: android

I am working on my first actual app in Android Studio (have only done some hello world stuff). I want to add a navigation drawer to my swipe view activity (which is my main activity), but I do not know how. Could someone help me with my little problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic question so writing same thing again and again is some kind of time consuming thing so i will suggest you to search for some things like "Navigation Drawer in Activity" or you can go for this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer).

Comment: you can ask me for any issue if you feel you want to ask. You can also upvote my answer by clicking on up arrow in front of my answer. It would be really helpful for me too. Happy coding

Comment: okay but I can not iclude the drawer layout in the swipe view layout xml. So let's say I create a new xml, how do  make it work?